# Python: parse .exp to .csv

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv

I'm walking through a directory of `.exp` files, pulling the info I want from each of them, then compiling that into a `.csv` file. it's inelegant, but here it is:

```
    outMCfile = open(os.path.join(workingDir,'output',date+'NeptuneCdSummary.csv'),'w+')
for fn in fileList:
    infile = os.path.join(workingDir,fn)

    tmpHeader = open(infile,'r').readlines()
    for line in tmpHeader:
        line = line.strip()
        if line.startswith('Date') == True:
            doa = line.split(' ')
            doa = doa[1]
            outMCfile.write(doa)
            outMCfile.write("\n")
        elif line.startswith('Run number') == True:
            run = line.split(':')
            run = run[1].strip()
            outMCfile.write(run)
            outMCfile.write("\n")
        elif line.startswith('Comment') == True:
            comment = line.split(':')
            comment = comment[1].strip()
            outMCfile.write(comment)
            outMCfile.write("\n")
        elif line.startswith('SampleType') == True:
            samType = line.split(':')
            samType = samType[1].strip()
            outMCfile.write(samType)
            outMCfile.write("\n")
        elif line.startswith('Cycle') == True:
            labels = line
            outMCfile.write(labels)
            outMCfile.write("\n")
        elif line.startswith('***') == True:
            summary = line
            outMCfile.write(summary)
            outMCfile.write("\n")

outMCfile.close()
```

the last two conditions in the `for` loop (lines that start with "`Cycle`" and "`***`") are 22-32 columns wide (some are indices, some are floats).  How can I delimit the result?  I just get a long string of numbers in my output CSV for each of those lines all in the same cell.  And if I use `line.split()`, I get a `TypeError` regardless of which delimiter I use in the parenthesis.

The source line (this is all on one line) in the .exp looks like: 
"***    Mean    1.8101587019969535e-003 1.7032095329860594e-003 1.1496630243258965e-003 1.1713999855908471e-003 4.7688994577955489e-003 4.5573296301687650e-003 3.9930890896827012e-002 2.0829073529889563e-002 9.3939542591824787e-001 9.5234032647735734e-001 1.7299477345544945e+000 2.5226638938456563e+000 3.8076954346734854e-001 1.8291027001438267e+000 2.6616393017410958e+000 4.0608176179586236e-001 1.5082949448806580e+000 2.1780140681716909e-001 1.4703089782231224e-001"

But the output in the .csv no longer has the space separation; it's all in the first cell, whereas I'd like "***", "Mean", "#####...","####..." to each have their own cell.

Comment: the `== True` are superfluous. Maybe post one of those lines that cause trouble?

Comment: another nitpick: in `outMCfile = open(...)`, `'w'` mode is sufficient since you never read it.

Comment: Thanks for the tip re. the == True...I'm still at a clunky level in Python, always looking for more streamlining tips.  This is what's causing the problem, specifically: `elif line.startswith('Cycle') == True:
            labels = line
            outMCfile.write(labels)
            outMCfile.write("\n")
        elif line.startswith('***') == True:
            summary = line
            outMCfile.write(summary)
            outMCfile.write("\n")`

Comment: Could you give an example of the lines for the cases of interest?

Comment: did you try newline = summary.split() and work on newline ?

Comment: input: `elif line.startswith('***') == True:
            summary = line
            outMCfile.write(summary)
            outMCfile.write("\n")` I get this in the .csv output: Mean 1.8101587019969535e-003 1.7032095329860594e-003 1.1496630243258965e-003 1.1713999855908471e-003 4.7688994577955489e-003 4.5573296301687650e-003...etc. all as one continuous string of numbers in the same cell.  I'd rather not have to re-specify how it should be delimited when I finally open it in excel later on (apologies, this is difficult to show on here...)

Comment: Two more improvement suggestions: 1) `.readliness` + `line.strip()` -> `for line in (line.strip() for line in <file>)`; 2) use the [`csv` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well it's obvious now, in all previous elifs you write one value from the list, and in the last two you try to write the entire list to file. You can only write strings to file. Convert it to string again:

```
outMCfile.write(','.join(line.split()))
```

or simpler perhaps:

```
 outMCfile.write(line.replace(' ', ','))
```

assuming the comma is your csv separator

Comment: ahhh, wow, it does seem obvious now...I'll never do that again!  Many thanks to everyone.  It's working like a charm now.